# Type class instances for type synonyms are disallowed

Tags: purescript

I tried to implement a `show` function for a custom type called `Token`. I have tried the following code:

```hs
type Token =
    { identifier :: String
    , value :: String
    }

instance showToken :: Show Token where
    show t = "(Token " <> t.identifier <> ", " <> t.value <> ")"
```

I get the following error however:

```
Type class instances for type synonyms are disallowed.
```

The error provides a [link](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/TypeSynonymInstance.md), but it does not provide any helpful information. What does it mean and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `newtype` to give `Token` a distinct type from the record. Otherwise, you're simply defining a type alias.

```hs
import Prelude

newtype Token = Token
  { identifier :: String
  , value :: String
  }

instance showToken :: Show Token where
  show (Token t) = "(Token " <> t.identifier <> ", " <> t.value <> ")"
```